# Is there a pre-made solution for distributed messaging in a python/kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy

For example, a program like rabbitMQ. But I want to be able to include it in my compiled package that goes out. That way, there are no special requirements for setup outside just running my .exe or .dmg file.

I'm curious if something like this is already possible or if I'll need to put something together myself.

Comment: rabbitMQ site states that there is a pure python module pika[http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika] Why not just include that in your app's root directory and it will be incldued in the apk.